# Range slider starts with letter

Tags: jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap, css

I designed one range slider it starts with 0-4.It displays 0,1,2,3,4.Means min=0 and max=4.Now i want 0 replace 'F'.

For ex: F,1,2,3,4.It is possible or not?

Comment: Could you provide some code? Use [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net) for convenience.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use regex to swap those elements
i've created jsbin where you can see a short demo for it

Demo:
https://jsbin.com/tuyuhafeco/edit?html,js,console,output

Regex explanation:
https://regex101.com/r/sJ4cV5/1

Comment: this my code Ranger.rangeSlider({ type: "single",
            min: 0,           
            max: 4,
           
            grid: true,
            
        }); How to change min value?

Comment: Would you prepare a working jsfiddle.net for this? It's going to be much easier.

Comment: i'm using ionRangeSlider plugins if any problem in jsffiddle.net

Comment: https://jsbin.com/nobivekula/edit?js,console,output Here is jsbin, you can take a look and modify your code as here :)

Comment: No problem, would be great if you'd set this answer as correct! Cheers